# Filtering using Google Guava API

Tags: java, guava

Is there a way to check if all objects in a list have the same attribute with Google Guava API?

Moreover, is there a way to send more parameters to Predicate?

Let's said I want to filter all my objects with string that I am getting from the user, 
and I want the Predicate to use this parameter when applying the filter.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own predicate as follows:

```
class MyPredicate implements Predicate<MyObject> {
  private final String parameter;

  public MyPredicate(String parameter) {this.parameter = parameter;}

  boolean apply(MyObject input) {
  // apply predicate using parameter.
  }
}
```

You can then filter by doing:

```
Iterables.filter(myIterable, new MyPredicate(myParameter));
```

You should be wary though that this performs a lazy filter.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to check if all objects in a list have the same attribute with Google Guava API?

Yes:

```
Foo first = list.get(0).getFoo();
boolean allSameFoo = Iterables.all(list, element -> element.getFoo().equals(first));
```

Or, if you're not using Java 8 yet:

```
final Foo first = list.get(0).getFoo();
boolean allSameFoo = Iterables.all(list, new Predicate<Bar> {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Bar element) {
        return element.getFoo().equals(first);
    }
});
```

> is there a way to send more parameters to Predicate

Yes:

```
String s = getFromUser();
Iterables.filter(list, element -> element.getFoo().equals(s));
```

Or, if you're not using Java 8 yet:

```
final String s = getFromUser();
Iterables.filter(list, new Predicate<Bar> {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Bar element) {
        return element.getFoo().equals(s);
    }
});
```

It seems you don't really know how inner classes work, so you should read the tutorial about them: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html.

Comment: But what if my predicate is a real class not Anonymous Class

Comment: Then it's even simpler: you pass the string as an argument to the constructor, and the constructor stores it in a field of the predicate, just as Benjy's answer shows.

Comment: Ok this is what I thought  TNX